# Locally override metropolis's titleformat section=smallcaps

Tags: beamer, small-caps, beamer-metropolis, titlecaps

I'm making a presentation that must follow a given template. This template includes the following line:

```
\usetheme[titleformat frame=allsmallcaps, titleformat section=smallcaps]{metropolis}
```

The thing is: one of the frame titles has proper names in it, and I must capitalize them. I can't seem to find a way to override it in that single location.

I know I can remove that and just write them in smallcaps, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\metroset` in the middle of the document to change settings of the theme. These settings will affect the remainder of the document, unless you put the command and the content it should apply to in a group (i.e., between curly brackets).

Note that the `\metroset` command is specific for the `metropolis` theme. For other themes commands like `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\normalfont}` (among others) can be used to change settings within the document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts} % use any font with sans serif smallcaps here, other options possible
\usetheme[titleformat frame=allsmallcaps, titleformat section=smallcaps]{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Frame Title}
\end{frame}

% note the extra { and } around \metroset and the frame
{\metroset{titleformat frame=regular}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another Frame Title}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]